# Which linux os is good for FFmpeg?

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, centos

Which Linux OS(Debian, centos, ubuntu) is good for the video encoding using ffmpeg? This is to install on dedicated server.

Comment: Why should one not be good for `ffmpeg`? And what is the definition of `good` in this case ? Do you have any experience regarding that question or why you ask? That would be valuable information, otherwise it will likely be closed as opinion-based.

Comment: This looks like opinion based question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory you can extract more performance from ffmpeg by compiling it from sources using the latest GCC version in which case you could go for Fedora or Arch Linux however both these distros require a lot of maintenance.

If you expect this server to work for many years and you don't want to spend more time than absolutely necessary, you could install Ubuntu LTS, Debian or CentOS 8 on it.